# HttpPost won't be called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been at this for an hour now and I haven't got a clue what I am doing wrong.

I got the following `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveActivity", "Dashboard", new { id = a.Id },htmlAttributes: null)
```

This targets the following Method in my `DashboardController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveActivity(int id)
{
    activityRepo.Delete(activityRepo.GetById(id));

    return RedirectToAction("ActivityDetails");
}
```

For some reason this error gets returned:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its  dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is  temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that  it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /Dashboard/RemoveActivity/564

A table row with the Id of 564 does exist in the database. It worked a few hours ago.
Any help is appreciated. I am clueless!

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace HaarlemFestival_Web
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you debug this, e.g. put a breakpoint in RemoveActivity and see if it gets hit? Are there any exception logs? I can't immediately see how that code would generate a 404 anyway.

Comment: When I do that the RemoveActivity is not even being hit :/

Comment: Show how the routes are configured as well as the controller that action is defined in.

Comment: ok action links are used for HTTP GET requests and you have your action tagged with a `HttpPost` attribute

Comment: Ah I see, then how do I call this Remove method?

Comment: Id which you are passing into the action have a value or it's null ?

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.ActionLink()` generates a `<a>` tag which makes a GET, not a POST. You need to include a `<form>` element and submit the value to your POST method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveActivity", "Dashboard", new { id = a.Id }))
{
    <input type="submit value="Remove" />
}
```

and you can style your submit button to look like a link if that is what you want visually

I also suggest you add the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` method in the `<form>` and add the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute to your method to prevent CSRF attacks.

You should also consider validating that the current user does have the permission to delete that record.

Note that since you method is changing data, it should be a POST, so do not be tempted to just remove the `[HttpPost]` attribte from your method so that the link works.

Answer (score 1):

Because @Html.ActionLink will render an anchor tag, Clicking on which is always "GET" request. So if you want an HTTP-Post method you need to override its behavior using javascript like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveActivity", "Dashboard", new { id = a.Id ,@class="post_link"},htmlAttributes: null);

[HttpPost]
public String RemoveActivity(int id)
{
    activityRepo.Delete(activityRepo.GetById(id));

    return "Remove/ActivityDetails";
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("a.post_link").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post($(this).attr("href"),function(data){
          //got your redirection link and do a redirection request at here
          window.location = data;
      });
    });    
  });    
</script>
```

Comment: Changed my remove method from Post to Get, now it works. Is that acceptable?

Comment: it's OK. But you will send the "GET" request. You can check the differences between HTTP POST AND HTTP GET at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp .And choose the right solution for you

Comment: @Teije - is it acceptable - NO! absolutely not. A delete action should never be a GET. You need a form and submit button to make a POST to your method (and add the ID as a route value in the `BeginForm()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , very simple way

In you view  just place anchor tag:   // make sure you have Id coming here

```
 <a href="#" onclick="RemoveActivity(@a.Id)">Remove</a>
```

Jquery block:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function RemoveActivity(index) {

                    var urlBase = '/Dashboard/RemoveActivity/';
                    $.ajax({
                        url: urlBase,
                        data: { id: index },
                        success: function (result) {                             
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                        }
                    });
                }                

</script>
```

keep your controller action as post method only. I hope this helps.

Comment: You are on the right track. check the URL however. The post is not sending anything in the body. The URL would look something like `"/Dashboard/RemoveActivity/" + index` or use `@Url.Action`

Comment: we are sending id with data parameter in ajax calll

Comment: granted but the route template expects `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and the action is not using `FromBody` attribute